# MVC C# want my query to be able to return null elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity, code-first

So I have a simple line of code that I'm using to check if the database already has data, but when it doesn't it returns an error (stating that nothing could be found in the database).

Basically I'm trying to get it so that the query can return null aswell? here's the code I'm using:

```
 var ac = db.Houses.Single(d => d.address1 == reviewmodelview.Address1);
```

So as you can see its really quite simple, I will use the ac variable to run an if statement to see if its null or has has a value. But when its null, it throws an exception. Is there a piece of code I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Single()` use `FirstOrDefault()` that should do what you want.

Comment: or even `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: @Daniel - I always prefer to use First/FirstOrDefault as Single/SingleOrDefault throws an exception if there is more then 1 matching row, which might be useful in some situations but I have yet to see one of them.

Answer (score 0):

*Try*  `SingleOrDefault` -  **It will returns the default value for the *type* if the result set returns 0.**

```
    var ac = db.Houses.SingleOrDefault(d => d.address1 == reviewmodelview.Address1);

    if(ac == null)
    {
      // null check 
    }
```